# Why were prefixes repeated as postverbal prepositions?

Tags: english, etymology, latin, french, romance-languages

> French: [s'abstenir de](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/abstain)    Spanish: [abstenerse de](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=abstain)    English: [abstain [from] (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abstain&searchmode=none)
>   [<--] 
>       late 14c., "to withhold oneself," from Old French abstenir (14c.), earlier astenir (13c.) "hold (oneself) back, refrain, **abstain (from)**, practice abstinence," from Latin abstinere "withhold, keep back, keep off," from ***ab(s)-* "from, away from"** (see [ab-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ab-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + tenere "to hold" (see [tenet](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tenet&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> French: [adhérer à](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/adhere)    Spanish: [adherir a](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=adhere)    English: [adhere to (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abstain&searchmode=none)
>   [<--] 
>   directly from Latin *adhaerentem* (nominative *adhaerens*), present participle of *adhaerere* "stick to," from *ad-* "to" (see ad-) + *haerere* "to stick" (see [hesitation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hesitation&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> French: [appartenir à](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/appertain)   English: [appertain [to] (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=appertain&searchmode=none)
>   [<--]
>       late 14c., from Anglo-French apartenir, Old French apartenir (12c.) "**be related to**; be incumbent upon," from Late Latin appertinere "to pertain to," from ***ad-* "to, completely"** (see [ad-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ad-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + pertinere "to belong to" (see [pertain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pertain&allowed_in_frame=0)).

The literate Anglophones and Francophones were fluent in Latin, and so comprehended the Latin prefixes, when these verbs were borrowed from Latin. 
So why did English and French repeat the Latin prefix as a postverbal preposition? To wit, why weren't the intransitive verbs above NOT ditransitive?

For the following cognates, the English cognate appears more redundant than the French and Spanish ones. English  added the prefix ***en-***  , but 'ENdow' must still be followed by 'WITH'. French didn't add any prefixes and conveys ***en-*** with 'de'.

> French : [doter qqn de qch](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/endow) (= endow somebody WITH something) 
>   Spanish: [dotar de algo a](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=endow)
>   English: [endow (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=endow&searchmode=none) [...] from ***en-* "in"** (see [en-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=en-&allowed_in_frame=0) (1)) + Old French *douer* "endow,"
>   from Latin *dotare* "bestow" (see [dowry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dowry&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Comment: Didn't Latin verbs like *abstinere, appertinere* and so on express some of their meaning through the case suffix on the objects? E.g., *abstinere* "to abstain" would have had one of its objects (= the object being avoided) in the ablative case, because that is the case typically taken by the prefix/preposition *ab*  ("from"). Since neither French nor English has the range of case suffixes that Latin does, the repetition of the verbal prefix/preposition may have helped to fill in the meaning that the case suffixes would originally have contributed.

Comment: And alongside the loss of casemarking, English stopped using prefixes the Latin way. Use of native prepositions as prefixes has been mostly unproductive since the 12th century. A Latin prefix is not an English preposition; and whether or not you're Latinist enough to recognize the relationship to Latin prepositions, if you're writing in English you have to follow English syntax, which demands that prepositions stand immediately before their objects.

Comment: @user8017: This. Note also that Latin itself sometimes repeated the preposition: I wouldn't be surprised to see *decessit de monte* or *excessit ex antro*.

Comment: Like the extremely common _off of_, people often repeat prepositions, pronouns, auxiliaries, and even affixes. After a while, it can get to be a habit, like the "is, is" construction.